# Is it possible to handle React events using the Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension. The target site began to use React to change some elements of the site. Can I handle these React events in order to perform the necessary operations in the extension?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: What exactly are the necessary operations you need to perform? Can you give an example?

Comment: @ArslanAli website via React makes asynchronous loading of some elements such as header text, dropdown menu. I need to intercept this moment in order to modify these. I could try using something like MutationObserver, Arrive.js, but I would like to see if there is a more elegant way to intercept.

Comment: IDK about a more elegant way to intercept, I would have gone with MutationObserver

Comment: I think you could try monkey-patching `react-dom`'s host config so whenever react tries to render the changes you get notified. It defines how virtual DOM changes get rendered in a browser. [Here](https://blog.atulr.com/react-custom-renderer-2/) you can read more about it.